# Why my Angular app recognizes my valid routes as invalid?

Tags: angular2-routing, angular5, angular4-router

I have two basic two basic `NgModules` and routing ones as well in this app, core (for header, footer and home pages) and an `auth` for authentication basically. without using the `wildcard` the app routes perfectly between `components`. once I introduce the invalid routing the only component that loads is the home one. 
I am routing from my header component, i.e. `routerLink="/signin"`
any idea why is this happening?

The following is my code,

**CoreModule**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      HeaderComponent,
      FooterComponent,
      SidenavLeftComponent,
      HomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      CommonModule,
      BrowserModule,
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
      MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
      MDBBootstrapModulePro.forRoot(),
      NgbModule.forRoot(),
      AppRoutingModule
    ],
    exports: [
      HeaderComponent,
      FooterComponent,
      SidenavLeftComponent,
      HomeComponent,
      AppRoutingModule
        ],
    schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
  })
  export class CoreModule { }
```

**AppRoutingModule**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home' , pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'not-found', component: NotFoundComponent, data: { message: 'We Could Not Serve Your Request!'}},
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '/not-found',  pathMatch: 'full'}
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [
      RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules})
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule {
    }
```

**AuthModule**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SigninFormComponent,
    SignupRequestFormComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MDBBootstrapModule,
    MDBBootstrapModulePro,
    NgbModule,
    AuthRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

**AuthRoutingModule**

```
const authRoutes: Routes = [
 { path: 'signin', component: SigninFormComponent },
 { path: 'signup', component: SignupRequestFormComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(authRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AuthRoutingModule { }
```

**AppModule**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ErrorPageComponent,
    NotFoundComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    CoreModule,
    AuthModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    MDBSpinningPreloader,
    UserService,
    ConfigService,
    AuthGuard,
    { provide: Http, useClass: AuthenticatedHttpService }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AppModule

```
 @NgModule({
    .....
    imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     BrowserAnimationsModule,
     FormsModule,
     HttpModule,
     CoreModule,
     AuthModule,
     AppRoutingModule
    ],
```

You are loading CoreModule first, so your AppRoutingModule is loaded first and every invalid routes and the routes which are not defined there are being redirected to your widlcard expression.

```
    const appRoutes: Routes = [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'home' , pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
        { path: 'not-found', component: NotFoundComponent, data: { message: 'We Could Not Serve Your Request!'}},
        { path: '**', redirectTo: '/not-found',  pathMatch: 'full'}
    ];
```

So either you should load AuthModule before CoreModule in AppModule declarations or remove wildcard expression from AppRoutingModule and put it inside AuthRoutingModule.